# download all questions asked and answers received from a website stackexchange account?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I've got a bunch of questions posted on a given stackexchange site, for example, superuser, and I would like to download/export them in a format that I can store locally in my computer. How can I download or export all questions asked and answers received from a given website stackexchange account? Any ideas?

EDIT: SQL query would be fine, but I haven't found out how. I want all my questions+received.answers in text output. Anyone?

Comment: We'll be moving this to Meta soon.

Comment: SQL query would be fine, but I haven't found out how. I want all my questions+answers in a text output. Anyone?

Comment: Go to `http://data.stackexchange.com/`, click on the site name, click on *Compose Query* and enter e.g. `SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE OwnerUserId=84604`. Then click *Download CSV*. Everything else depends on what you want to use the output for, in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options:

- Use the [data dumps](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)
- Write SQL queries for [Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and download the results
- Use the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage).

It really depends on what you want to do with how much of the content.

---

Note that all content is licensed as [Creative Commons BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and you need to adhere to the license when publishing.